# How to count the number of lines in the middle of a pipe

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, control-flow

I want to count the number of lines in a pipe and then continue the pipe depending on the outcome.

I tried

```bsh
x=$(printf 'faa\nbor\nbaz\n' \
  | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l) 2>&1 \
  | if [[ $x -ge 2 ]]; then
      grep a
    else
      grep b
    fi
```

But it doesn't filter at all (neither for "a" nor for "b").  That was pretty unexpected as at least these work as expected:

```bsh
printf 'faa\nbor\nbaz\n' | if true; then grep a; else grep b; fi
printf 'faa\nbor\nbaz\n' | if false; then grep a; else grep b; fi
```

It seems that I can not redirect the stderr from inside the command substitution as this does also not work (in bash). It prints all three lines:

```bsh
x=$(printf 'faa\nbor\nbaz\n' | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l) 2>&1 | grep a
```

In zsh it only prints two lines.

But in both shells the variable x is not set after the pipeline and not even during the second half of the pipeline.

What can I do to count the lines in a pipeline and then act depending on that number? I would like to avoid temp files.

Comment: zsh is not compatible with bash or any other posix shell (except ksh maybe), and doesn't claim to be so. Are you looking for a bash, or zsh solution?

Comment: I would prefer a bash solution but am interested in any enlightenment on how to do this at all.

Comment: Each part of a pipeline is started independently of the other parts of the same pipeline. This means that `$x` can't be available in the middle of the pipeline if it's set in one of the other stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553866/108618#comment1028658_553866) is true:

> Each part of a pipeline is started independently of the other parts of the same pipeline. This means that `$x` can't be available in the middle of the pipeline if it's set in one of the other stages.

This doesn't mean you cannot do anything. A pipeline may be considered the main data channel, still processes can communicate using side channels: files, named fifos or whatever (although sometimes you need to be extra careful and not to let them block).

You want to count the number of lines and conditionally process the whole data stream later. This means you need to get to the end of the stream and only then pass the entire stream. So you need to save the whole stream somehow. A temporary file looks like a sane approach. You should split your pipe into at least two parts. The first part should save the data in a file; then the lines should be counted (this task may belong to the first part, I think); then the last part should get the number, read the file to receive the data from the start, and act accordingly.

---

If you really want to avoid temporary files then some part of your pipeline should act somehow like `sponge`. To avoid side channels the number of lines should be passed as the very first line of the output and the remaining part of the pipeline should understand this protocol.

Consider this command:

```
sed '$ {=; H; g; p;}; H; d'
```

It accumulates lines in a hold space. If there is at least one line then after receiving the last line `sed` prints the number of lines followed by an empty line and the actual input.

The empty line is unnecessary but it appears "naturally" from this simple code. Instead of trying to avoid it in `sed`, I would simply deal with it later in the pipe (e.g. with `sed '2 d'`).

Example usage:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed '$ {=; H; g; p;}; H; d' | sed '2 d' | {
   if ! IFS= read -r nlines; then
      echo "0 lines. Nothing to do." >&2
   else
      echo "$nlines lines. Processing accordingly." >&2
      if [ "$nlines" -ge 2 ]; then
         grep a
      else
         grep b
      fi
   fi
}
```

Notes:

- `IFS= read -r` is an overkill because the first line is well defined and it contains a sole number (or it doesn't exist).
- I used `/bin/sh`. The code will run in Bash as well.
- You cannot assume `sed` is able to hold any arbitrary amount of data. [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says:

  > The pattern and hold spaces shall each be able to hold at least 8192 bytes.

  So it may be the limit is only 8192 bytes. On the other hand I can imagine a temporary file holding 1TB of data easily. Maybe don't avoid temporary files at all cost.

---

The title says "count the number of lines" but your example tries to decide if the number is 2 or more (N or more in general). These problems are not equivalent. After the 2nd (Nth) line  of input you know the answer to the latter problem, even lines are going to appear indefinitely. The above code cannot handle indefinite input. Let's fix it to some degree.

```
sed '
7~1 {p; d}
6 {H; g; i \
6+
p; d}
$ {=; H; g; p}
6! {H; d}
'
```

This command behaves like the previous solution, except when it gets to the 6th line it assumes (prints) the number of lines is `6+`. Then the already seen lines are printed and the following lines (if any) get printed as soon as they appear (`cat`-like behavior).

Example usage:

```
#!/bin/sh

threshold=6

sed "
$((threshold+1))~1 {p; d}
$threshold {H; g; i \
$threshold+
p; d}
$ {=; H; g; p}
${threshold}! {H; d}
" | sed '2 d' | {
   if ! IFS= read -r nlines; then
      echo "0 lines. Nothing to do." >&2
   else
      echo "$nlines lines. Processing accordingly." >&2
      if [ "$nlines" = "$threshold+" ]; then
         grep a
      else
         grep b
      fi
   fi
}
```

Notes:

- Fixed "to some degree" because the limitation of `sed` (whatever the limitation is in your case) still applies. But now `sed` processes at most `$threshold` number of lines; if `$threshold` is low enough then it should be OK.
- The example code only tests against `$threshold+` but the protocol allows you to distinguish between 0, 1, 2, …, threshold-minus-one and threshold-or-more lines.

---

<sup>I'm not very skilled in `sed`. If my `sed` code can be simplified, please leave me a hint in a comment.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the nice separation of my different problems! The final script does not work correctly though. More specifically the`{sed ...; cat; }` trick. It seems that cat does not get any further input as I lose all lines beyond `$threshold`. It might work to tell sed to only store lines until `$threshold` and then print all further lines directly but I was not able to code it right away. Well that's s[ea]d.

Comment: @Lucas This was not the case in my tests in Debian, but I suspected `sed` (another implementation of it?) may close the input. The answer now relies on `sed`, not on `sed`+`cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion and the sed code from Kamil I found this awk solution:

```
awk -v th="$threshold" '
  function print_lines() { for (i in lines) print lines[i] }
  NR < th { lines[NR] = $0 }
  NR > th { print }
  NR == th { print th; print_lines(); print }
  END { if (NR < th) { print NR; print_lines(); } }' \
| if read nlines; then
    if [ "$nlines" -eq "$threshold" ]; then
      grep a
    else
      grep b
    fi
  fi
```